# Are there any other solutions to this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Consider the equation $1-t = tx^{1-2t}$ for some complex number $t$ and real $x$.
Are there any other solutions to this equation besides $\Re(t) = \frac{1}{2}$ ?

My attempt: The above equation can be written in the form               $\dfrac{x^t}{t} = \dfrac{x^{1-t}}{1-t}$

Which can be interpreted as
                                                            $\int_0^x u^{-\alpha} \mathrm {d}u = \int_0^x u^{\alpha-1} \mathrm {d}u $, 
where $\alpha= \Re(t)$.

Interpreting these integrals as areas under the respective curves, observe that the equality requires that $-\alpha = \alpha - 1$, which yields $\alpha= 1/2$, as required ?

Comment: How do you define $x^t$ for complex values of $x,t$?

Comment: Please note that $x$ is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one more solution. Roughly, take logarithms on both sides:
$$\log(1-t) = \log(tx^{1-2t}) = \log(t) + (1-2t)\log(x)$$

Reordering and taking exponentials:
$$x = \exp\left(\frac{1}{1-2t}\log\left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)\right) = \left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)^\frac{1}{1-2t}$$

Comment: Are logarithms of complex numbers treated in the same way as those for reals ?

Comment: If you restrict $t$ to $(0,1)$ then the logarithm and $x$ are real.

Comment: Okay Gammamaster & AugSB, thank you very much.

Comment: This solution is not correct, it should be $log(x)$ on the left

Comment: You are right. I forgot the exponential. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This equation has infinitely many solutions in the following form:

$$
x=\left(\frac{1}{t}-1 \right)^{1/(1-2t)}
$$

[image: You can plot it and see all possible solutions]

Maybe you should clarify your question?